# Why do we need to use the front-channel for an OAuth authorization request?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, authorization, single-page-application

I've been struggling with this and would love to see if any OAuth experts here have an answer.

For context, I'm trying to integrate OAuth into an existing first-party (internal) front-end client that lives on a subdomain. It's a single-page application. I have an authorization server that has an `/oauth2/authorize` and `oauth2/token` endpoint and I'm working with the OAuth 2 with PKCE authorization flow.

In all the examples I've seen externally, it seems like the recommendation is to make a top-level redirect to the authorization URL initial login . And for silently re-authenticating a user (if they were already logged in), using an invisible iFrame set to the authorization URL (and postMessaging the code back to the parent window).

I'm trying to understand what prevents me from making a front-channel request to my `/authorize` endpoint via Javascript. Something simple like...

`const { state, code } = await fetch(authorizationUrl)`

For the login case, I can handle a 403 error back from the AS and then redirect them to login from the client-side. For the re-authenticating case (i.e. client has an expired refresh token but is still logged in), this is great because I just get a 200 response and the code back directly in the JSON body and I can use it immediately. There is no top-level redirect, no hassle of saving app state, etc.

It seems like as long as the AS is willing to return the `{ state, code }` via JSON, this should work. This means that

1. The AS authorize endpoint must be configured to allow CORS on select origins. This seems okay in a first-party context since I know which origins I should allow.
2. The AS must be sent client credentials (session cookies) with the request (otherwise the AS would have no idea how to determine if the user is logged in). In JS, this would be as simple as adding `credentials: true`. As long as the cookie credentials have `Same-Site: None` and the cookie is part of the same domain (cross-domain would not work since some browsers disable cross-site cookie sharing nowadays!)

I feel like I'm missing something crucial here. But at the same time, my prototype is working, so I'd love to get some input from experienced folks here.

Comment: I'm not an expert but I think you mixed up technology; [the PKCE flow](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce) don't talk about IFrame and cookie but token and (eventually) refresh token. From the perspective of the Authorization URL when you pass an invalid token it responds with an error which, in turn, you can redirect the user to the Authentication URL.

Comment: @Max Silent refresh is a way for the user to refresh their authorization using PKCE without doing a redirect. For example, the web app can open an invisible iFrame, do a top-level navigation to the authorization URL with prompt=none and instead a 301/302 Redirect, get a server response with HTML/JS document that has the auth code and uses the Post Message API to send the code back to parent window. Preventing a redirect is useful b/c for SPAs, it is undesirable to navigate the user from the page to re-authorize. This standard is used in a number of OAuth providers like Auth0 for SPAs